# Call a function at last iteration of a .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to execute a function received by props at the last iteration of a map loop,

I tried to execute the function when index is equal to array.length - 1, but it stills execute the function at every iteration, so the console.log("last index") appears at every iteration,

The idea is to execute this.props.handleTotalPrice with totalPrice as parameter once I'm done to increment totalPrice at every iteration,

I tried the following code :

```js
products && products.map((product, index) => {
  const cost = Math.round((product.price * planningData[product.productId][planningType]) * 100) / 100;
  nbCount += parseInt(planningData[product.productId][planningType]);
  totalPrice += cost;

  if (index === products.length - 1) {
    console.log("last index")
    this.props.handleTotalPrice(totalPrice)
  }
});
```

Comment: If you're not returning inside a map, consider using `forEach` instead?

Comment: there's code rendered below, so I need map

Comment: Don't change state inside the render function, let alone JSX. I don't think it executes the function at every iteration; if you see tons of `last index` console entries, it's because you're creating an infinite render -> state change -> render loop

Comment: @Versifiction Your code does not save a map. It just uses map as a forEach

Comment: You need to completely change your approach; calculate the total cost whenever a product's data changes, not inside the render method.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to do the callback **after the map has completed** instead of doing it at the last iteration.

```
{products && products.map((product, index) => {
       const cost = Math.round((product.price * planningData[product.productId][planningType]) * 100) / 100;
       nbCount += parseInt(planningData[product.productId][planningType]);
       totalPrice += cost;
}) && this.props.handleTotalPrice(totalPrice);
```

Notes:

- Using `Array.map` without returning anything in the callback is the same as using a `Array.forEach`

## Writing JSX in React

It's usually recommended to only do simple operations in the `render` function, having a callback (like `handleTotalPrice`) in the render function is not recommended and can lead to bugs or huge performance issues.

Assuming you are using a React version that supports hooks, I would change the code like this:

```
const MyComponent({ handleTotalPrice }) {
    const products = {/* your data*/};

    // Compute total price outside render function
    // Use `useMemo` so price is only recalculated if products list changes
    const totalPrice = useMemo(() => {
       if (!products) return 0;

       const total = products.reduce((sum, product) => {
           const cost = Math.round((product.price * planningData[product.productId][planningType]) * 100) / 100;
           return sum + cost;
       });

       // Call the callback when price changes
       handleTotalPrice(total);
    }, [products]);

    // Render
    return <div>
       {totalPrice}
    </div>;
}
```

Comment: it's inside JSX, I can't add your " && this.props.handleTotalPrice(totalPrice); " right after no ?

Comment: @Versifiction In that case, it's better to just move it in a separate function named `renderProducts`, as it will be more efficient and also easier to read/maintain.

Comment: This is bad practice; you're not supposed to put calculations like that inside JSX, let alone function calls.

Comment: @Versifiction Check out my edit for more notes about a better way to write JSX and React code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use `reduce` instead of `map` to iteratively run up a sum, then return the value, and do something with the result.

```
products &&
  this.props.handleTotalPrice(
    products.reduce((totalPrice, product) => {
        const cost = Math.round((product.price * planningData[product.productId][planningType]) * 100) / 100;
        nbCount += parseInt(planningData[product.productId][planningType]);
        totalPrice += cost;
        return totalPrice;
      }, 0)
    )
```